# JQuery Scroll Bottom issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, scroll

In our formbuilder, Whenever a field is dragged & dropped, it added to the tablet view. after addition few fields its automatically scroll to bottom.

Now issue here is. After adding field more than 10 fields, we are facing issue in scroll.
actually it has to scroll to bottom each time.

Comment: i think your problem here is your css... i tried to open it and boom your output are some kind of messy... so why try CSS Frameworks hope that could solve your problem...

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to make the scroll happen? I don't feel like digging.

Comment: @ClintBugs please clear cache & try again, we are getting it without any CSS bugs

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Here is the code `$('.button-drag').click(function () {
      
      
 // This solves the scrollTo dependency
 $('#frmb-0').animate({
 scrollTop: $('#frm-' + (last_id - 1) + '-item').offset().top
      }, 1000);
 return true;
      
 });`

Comment: @ClintBugs can you able to debug the issue?

Comment: no that's your problem so you should debugged it on your own.... i just give you an idea that may help...

Comment: giving scroll for ul. that scrollbar class having overflow:auto and fixing width and height only. how can correct this bug using css.